# Does the view close votes privilege include reopen votes?

Tags: support, privileges-page

According to the [view close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege page you can view close votes on your own question and vote to close/reopen your own questions with 250 reputation.

Nowhere does it state whether you can view reopen votes on your own question. Can you?

If you can this privilege page should be updated.

Comment: Most likely you can, we need account with 251-2999 rep to test. :)

Comment: I have one of those @Sha. The problem is that you also need a closed question with at least one reopen vote :-).

Comment: Easy! Flag --> Other --> "Please close for test purpose" --> Chat --> ask 3K+ member to cast a reopen vote. :)

Comment: I'd want the other reopen votes guaranteed as well!

Comment: Well, you'll have to take the risk. :D

Comment: That's what prompted the question @Mat. She asked if there were any tools that allowed her to see how close the question was to being reopened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can "view" reopen votes, or what there is to view of them. Unlike close votes, voting to reopen is just a matter of clicking the link and confirming. There's really nothing to view there other than the number of reopen votes currently on the question.

When you vote to close, however, you are presented with a dialog which lets you see how many votes each close reason currently has, which is what the privilege is referring to. You can also still see the number of votes in the link, similar to reopen votes.

As long as you can cast a close or reopen vote on the question, you *will* see the count next to it (unless there's currently zero votes).

Comment: Cool beans... makes sense. Now, having volunteered, how are you going to put that into the privilege pages :-)?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: There's not really anything I could do. The privilege itself is named "view close votes" in the side bar - so if that's the part you're complaining about, users can't change the title. You'd have to bug a dev if you really want it changed. Honestly, most of that information can probably be duplicated from the full close/reopen privilege page.